# Living in Singapore, what’s this bug? Found an identical one in my house on the floor

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image: small brown bug with a prominent dark stripe on its back, about the size of half a grain of rice]

Hi! I’m living in Singapore (Southeast Asia). Found a small brown bug with a prominent dark stripe on its back like the pictured one, about the size of half a grain of rice. It was wandering around on my living room floor and I have no idea where it came from. I live in a high floor apartment.

Comment: This is a beetle. They typically have hard wings (so-called elytra) that distinguish them from many other insect groups. Globally, there are almost 200 described beetle families with more than 300,000 species - so, I can't even tell the family, sorry. But most likely, it was in your appartment accidentally.